# Searching a table with Selenium, checking a row for a value, and clicking a checkbox in the same row if the value is present

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a list of ID numbers that I need to compare against a table on a website. If a row in the table has text that matches one of the ID numbers in my list, I need to click a check box that is in that same row as the ID number. I've provided the HTML for the table below.

How do I go about grabbing the ID numbers from my list and then using Selenium to search the table for them and select the checkbox in that row?

Here is what I've tried so far, but I feel completely off here:

```py
MyList = {'1234500', '5432100', '00000989'}

Table = driver.find_element_by_id('tblActivities')
Table_Row = Table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
Table_Cell = Table_Row.find_elements_by_xpath('span[contains(text(), "' + MyList + '")])
```

I'm trying to compare my list to the value found here:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000"
```

```html
<table id="tblActivities" class="commonTable1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                  <colgroup>
                   <col>
                   <col>
                   <col>
                   <col align="left">
                   <col align="left">
                   <col align="left">
                   <col align="left">
                   <col align="left">
                   <col>
                   <col>
                   <col>
                   <col>
                   <col>
                   <col>
                   <col>
                  </colgroup>

                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                                <th colspan="15"> <span>1-5&nbsp;of&nbsp;43&nbsp;Activities</span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody><tr>

                    <th width="10px"> 

                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkUncheckAll" value="on" onclick="handleQueueListEvent(this);" id="checkUncheckAll" class="commonCheckBox">

                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <span id="hdrDeadline" onclick="orderBy(this);" class="commonLink">
                            <nobr>Deadline</nobr>

                                <img src="gif">

                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th><span><nobr>ID</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Type</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Status</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Assigned</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Behalf</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_0" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Type</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_1" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Amount</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_2" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Counterparty</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_3" style="display: none;">


                            <span><nobr>Value</nobr></span>

                    </th>
                    <th class="col_4" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Relationship</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_5" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Target</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Location Context</nobr></span></th>
                  </tr>


                  <tr>
                      <td colspan="14" class="commonHeaderContentSeparator"><img src="  Desktop/common/images/spacer.gif" height="1" style="display:block"></td>
                  </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_0" class="commonCheckBox">


                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">00000000</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending                                 

                                <br>Not Eligble

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                           Name 
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                              000000<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_1" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">00000000</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring Event

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Nothing

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                           Name 
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>
                              000000<br>Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                                Strat

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_2" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">0000000</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Mandatory

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                          Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                              000000<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_3" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">0000000</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring Event

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Mandatory

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                          Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                             0000000<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Account Type

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_4" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01 - January   

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">0000000</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring Event

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Mandatory

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                          Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                              Acct<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Account

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                 </tbody></table>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check value from you list available or not in the table use `.find_elements_by_xpath`, utilize `len`:

```
len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="tblActivities"]//tr//td//input[@value="value_from_list"]'))
```

And use loop to achieve you mean:

```
mylist = {'1234500', '5432100', '00000989'}

for value in mylist:
    if(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="tblActivities"]//tr//td//input[@value="' +value +'"]'))>0):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="tblActivities"]//tr//td//input[@value="' +value +'"]').click()
    else:
        print('not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath can be created to identify the checkbox using Xpath axes. Using ancestor and child relationships in rows and columns. For more details on XPath axes please refer: [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Need to find relation between elements and use it to locate checkbox. Here is XPath that can be used:

> //span[contains(text(),"ID_TO_FIND")]/ancestor::tr//input[@class="commonCheckBox"]

This XPath can be used in your example code:

```
MyList = {'1234500', '5432100', '00000989'}

Table = driver.find_element_by_id('tblActivities')
Table_Row = Table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
CheckBox = Table_Row.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"' + MyList + '")]/ancestor::tr//input[@class="commonCheckBox"]');
```

Here is an updated HTML you shared that can be used to check the XPath:

```
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                                <th colspan="15"> <span>1-5&nbsp;of&nbsp;43&nbsp;Activities</span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody><tr>

                    <th width="10px"> 

                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkUncheckAll" value="on" onclick="handleQueueListEvent(this);" id="checkUncheckAll" class="commonCheckBox">

                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <span id="hdrDeadline" onclick="orderBy(this);" class="commonLink">
                            <nobr>Deadline</nobr>

                                <img src="gif">

                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th><span><nobr>ID</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Type</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Status</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Assigned</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Behalf</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_0" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Type</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_1" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Amount</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_2" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Counterparty</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_3" style="display: none;">


                            <span><nobr>Value</nobr></span>

                    </th>
                    <th class="col_4" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Relationship</nobr></span></th>
                    <th class="col_5" style="display: none;"><span><nobr>Target</nobr></span></th>
                    <th><span><nobr>Location Context</nobr></span></th>
                  </tr>


                  <tr>
                      <td colspan="14" class="commonHeaderContentSeparator"><img src="  Desktop/common/images/spacer.gif" height="1" style="display:block"></td>
                  </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_0" class="commonCheckBox">


                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">00000008</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending                                 

                                <br>Not Eligble

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                           Name 
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                              000000<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_1" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">00000009</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring Event

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Nothing

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                           Name 
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>
                              000000<br>Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                                Strat

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_2" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">0000001</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Mandatory

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                          Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                              000000<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_3" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01-Jan    

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">0000002</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring Event

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Mandatory

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                          Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                             0000000<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Account Type

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                      <td bpsid="240" activitytypeid="172" activitydescid="159" activitystateid="49" activitystatusid="10">
                        <span>

                                               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActivities" value="0000000" id="checkbox_4" class="commonCheckBox">

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>

                              <span>
                                  01 - January   

                              </span>

                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>

                          <span name="activityId" onclick="showActivityDetail(this);" class="commonLink">0000003</span>

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td><span>

                                Recurring Event

                              </span>
                      </td>

                      <td> 
                        <span>

                            Pending Approval                                

                                <br>Mandatory

                        </span>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <span>
                          Name
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                              Acct<br>Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <!-- 11.3 -->
                      <td class="col_0" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            Account

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_1" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_2" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_3" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                            USD&nbsp;

                                    000,000.00

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    <td class="col_4" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col_5" style="display: none;">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span>

                          Name

                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                 </tbody></table>
                 </body>
                 </html>
```